# Migrate to symfony 4 from symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, migration, symfony4, symfony-3.4

My project is currently setup with 3.4 version of symfony. I want to move to symfony4. So I moved to symfony4 as per suggestions in http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html.

In my current project there are many custom bundles are created in `src` directory. But now in Symfony 4 there is no bundle structure.

So please guide me how can I proceed with my existing bundles in Symfony4?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: While S4 no longer requires an AppBundle it will still handle bundles just fine.  Are you trying to use the new Flex directory format?

Answer (score 8):

You can follow the tuto made by Symfony, right here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html (you already done that)

And then to update you project structure: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#upgrade-to-flex

Comment: I have followed the same thing. Also I have mentioned the url in my question.

But I think you didn't understand my question properly. :)

Comment: If you have many custom bundles in your project then you may understand that a project in Symfony 4 is one and only one application so if you want to cut one application into many part you have to make as many application as part you want @JigarPancholi

Comment: If you want to conserve your bundles then follow [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html). You can also regroup all your bundles to make one application @JigarPancholi

Comment: It requires all namespaces to be start with ```App\```. So I need to change in all namespaces and use statement of my all bundles. I think it  is very cumbersome process.